# Multiple loops in set intervals with code in between

Tags: loop

The following lists the latest 5 blog posts, and then displays an ad, then continues off listing the remaining blog posts.

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    if( 5 > $wp_query->current_post ):
        the_title();
    else :
        break;
    endif;

endwhile;

echo 'My Ad';

while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    the_title();

endwhile;
```

Trying to update it so it does first 5 posts, AD, next "4" posts, then another AD, then remaining posts. So far no luck. Below is what I tried. It displays the first 5 latest posts, displays the ad, but then when it starts showing the next 4 latest posts it skips post number 6 and starts at post number 7 unfortunately.  Also after the second ad rather than continuing with the remaining posts, it starts the loop all over again.

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    if( 5 > $wp_query->current_post ): ?>
                     <?php the_title(); ?>
              <?php else :
                        break;
                    endif;

                  endwhile; ?>

                 Fixed Graphic

                 <?php while ( have_posts() ) :
                         the_post();

                         if( 10 > $wp_query->current_post ): ?>
                             <?php the_title(); ?>
                  <?php else :
                             break;
                         endif;

                       endwhile; ?>

                  Fixed Graphic

                 <?php // remaining posts
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();

                        the_title();

                    endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the codex, have_posts starts, steps through or rests the loop. [check codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts). 
In your code, when entering the second or n-th while, the posts loop is already started, so it steps to the next post, that's why it skips 6th element and starts over on the last while loop.
I would suggest you to include your ad code inside else -break branch.

Comment: Another solution would be to decrement the current_post property of $wp_query before each additional while loop. Though about this while I had a look through wp core Wp_Query class: it uses current_post property to decide what to do next inside have_posts method. Although untested, I think this solution would also do what you want.